# Como ordenar eixo de x que está em data em ordem crescente?

Tags: r, gráfico

Tenho um gráfico onde o eixo de x são as datas, mas ao ordenar de forma cronológica, pois antes estava em ordem alfabética, a informação do gráfico fica errada pois os dados seguem a ordem alfabética, nesse caso começando em abr/19 e não em set/18 e não indo de set/18 até set/19.

Utilizei esse code para ordenar os meses:

```
base_fox2$mês<-factor(base_fox2$mês, levels = c("set/18","out/18","nov/18",

"dez/18","jan/19","fev/19","mar/19","abr/19","mai/19","jun/19","jul/19",
"ago/19","set/19"))
```

E esse para criar o gráfico com as cinco variáveis

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(data=base_fox2,name='Fox',x=~base_fox2$mês,y=~base_fox2$quantidade,
        type='scatter',mode='lines')%>% 
  add_trace(y=~base_hb202$quantidade,name='HB20',type='scatter',mode='lines')%>% 
  add_trace(y=~base_gol2$quantidade,name='Gol',type='scatter',mode='lines')%>% add_trace(y=~base_palio2$quantidade,name='Palio',type='scatter',mode='lines')%>%
  add_trace(y=~base_punto2$quantidade,name='Punto',type='scatter',mode='lines')
```

Comment: Tente colocar `ordered = TRUE` em `factor`

Comment: Se vai fazer operações com os meses (p.e. calcular o tempo entre linhas), é melhor usar a classe Dates. Veja a ajuda para `as.Dates`. Se não é o caso, ordenar os fatores (comentário acima) é uma opção melhor.

Answer (score 1):

É melhor mudar a classe da coluna para classe `"Date"`, não para classe `"factor"`.

```
base_fox2$mês <- as.Date(paste("1", base_fox2$mês, sep = "/"), "%d/%b/%y")
```

Depois disto, se quiser só o mês e o ano, a função `as.yearmon` do pacote `zoo` é a função ideal.

```
base_fox2$mês <- zoo::as.yearmon(base_fox2$mês)
```

**Exemplo.**

Este exemplo só muda a classe da coluna com os dados da pergunta, não cria um dataframe nem traça o gráfico.

```
mes <- c("set/18","out/18","nov/18","dez/18","jan/19",
       "fev/19","mar/19","abr/19","mai/19","jun/19",
       "jul/19","ago/19","set/19")

mes <- as.Date(paste("1", mes, sep = "/"), "%d/%b/%y")
mes
# [1] "2018-09-01" "2018-10-01" "2018-11-01" "2018-12-01" "2019-01-01"
# [6] "2019-02-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01" "2019-06-01"
#[11] "2019-07-01" "2019-08-01" "2019-09-01"
```

Agora mudar para classe `"yearmon"`.

```
mes <- zoo::as.yearmon(mes)
mes
# [1] "set 2018" "out 2018" "nov 2018" "dez 2018" "jan 2019" "fev 2019" "mar 2019"
# [8] "abr 2019" "mai 2019" "jun 2019" "jul 2019" "ago 2019" "set 2019"
```